# Accessing elements from objects of a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linkedlist named subdata within a linkedlist named data and i would like to access the strings that i have added such as element1 using the linkedlist data. I have some code but i cannot make it work. I've tried a bunch of different things such as `Object obj=x.next();` instead of `LinkedList<Strings> obj=x.next();`. I also tried `x.next().get(0);` by itself in the print statement but no luck.

```
LinkedList<LinkedList> data=new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<String> subData=new LinkedList<>();

subData.add("element1");
data.add(subData);
Iterator x = data.listIterator(0);
while(x.hasNext()){
LinkedList<String> obj=x.next();
System.out.println(obj.get(0));
}
```

error:

```
 aclass.java:245: error: incompatible types
    LinkedList<String> obj=x.next();
                                 ^
      required: LinkedList<String>
      found:    Object
```

Comment: Well, your example *does* work, but you forgot the closing brace for your while loop!

Comment: i had the closing brace in my code but it is giving me an error, i'll post it above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generic typing was messed up. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> data=new LinkedList<>();
    LinkedList<String> subData=new LinkedList<>();

    subData.add("element1");
    data.add(subData);
    Iterator<LinkedList<String>> x = data.listIterator(0);
    while(x.hasNext()){
        LinkedList<String> obj=x.next();
        System.out.println(obj.get(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("elements1: " + data.iterator().next().iterator().next());
```

Comment: is there a cleaner approach to this?